# how to set highscore for quiz/game in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-games, flutter-dependencies

first time when we open to set high score as 0, in flutter
it will checked with score and update its value.
i too used shared preferences it does not work.

```
import './question.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

 class Quiz { 
 List<Question> _questions;
int _currentQuestionIndex = -1;
int _score = 0;
int _highscore;

  Future checkFirstSeen() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool _seen = (prefs.getBool('seen') ?? false);

   if (_seen) {
  _highscore=_highscore;
   } else {
  prefs.setBool('seen', true);
  _highscore=0;
    }
}

 Quiz(this._questions) {
    _questions.shuffle();
  }

   List<Question> get questions => _questions;
  int get length => _questions.length;
  int get questionNumber => _currentQuestionIndex+1;
  int get score => _score;
  int get highscore => _highscore;

 Question get nextQuestion {
  _currentQuestionIndex++;
  if (_currentQuestionIndex >= length) return null;
  return _questions[_currentQuestionIndex];
  }

 void answer(bool isCorrect) {
  if (isCorrect) _score++;
 }

 //added fun for highscore
 void check() {  
 if (_score > _highscore) {
    _highscore = _score;
 } else {
  _highscore = _highscore;
 }
 }

 }
```

this returns me always score and high score as same value(number).tell me solution

Comment: _highscore is not initialized, so it is null if you re-run your app after the first installation.

Comment: yeah when i run app it shows highscore and score as same value.

Comment: @PrakashKing Kindly do accept the answer if it did solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you need to edit the `Quiz.checkFirstSeen()` and `Quiz.check()` methods as follows:

```dart
Future<void> checkFirstSeen() async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  _highscore = prefs.getInt('highScore') ?? 0;
}

Future<void> check() async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  if (_score > _highscore) {
    _highscore = _score;
    await prefs.setInt('highScore', _highscore);
  }
}
```

In the code that you've posted, you don't actually need the `seen` shared variable, so I've removed that.

Comment: Compiler message:
lib/pages/score_page.dart:27:36: Error: Unexpected token 'await'.
   final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                                   ^^^^^
lib/pages/score_page.dart:30:5: Error: 'await' isn't a type.
    await prefs.setInt('highScore', highscore);
    ^^^^^
lib/pages/score_page.dart:30:11: Error: Expected ';' after this.
    await prefs.setInt('highScore', highscore);
          ^^^^^
lib/pages/score_page.dart:30:16: Error: Expected an identifier, but got '.'.
    await prefs.setInt('highScore', highscore);
               ^

Comment: @PrakashKing You can only use `await` inside `async` functions, it is a syntax error elsewhere. See https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures for details.